# Reducing noise in RRN prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, encog, supervised-learning

Using [Encog Machine Learning Framework](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog/), I am creating a NN to identify simple sequence patterns. Following are the configurations of my RNN:

```
var elmanNetworkPattern = new ElmanPattern {ActivationFunction = new ActivationTANH(),InputNeurons = 6};
elmanNetworkPattern.AddHiddenLayer(6);
elmanNetworkPattern.OutputNeurons = 1;
IMLMethod elmanNetwork = elmanNetworkPattern.Generate();
```

Below is the training dataset:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   output
-----------------------------------
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   2   3   4   5   6   8
1   2   3   4   5   6   9
1   2   3   4   5   6   10
1   2   3   4   5   6   12
1   2   3   4   5   6   13
1   2   3   4   5   6   86
```

Upon normalization with following criteria the normalized csv looks as follows:

```
encoganalyst.Script.Normalize.NormalizedFields[i].NormalizedHigh = 1;
encoganalyst.Script.Normalize.NormalizedFields[i].NormalizedLow = -1;
encoganalyst.Script.Normalize.NormalizedFields[i].ActualHigh = 100;
encoganalyst.Script.Normalize.NormalizedFields[i].ActualLow = 0;
encoganalyst.Script.Normalize.NormalizedFields[i].Action = NormalizationAction.Normalize;

a        b       c       d       e       f       output
-------------------------------------------------------------
-0.98   -0.96   -0.94   -0.92   -0.9    -0.88   -0.86
-0.98   -0.96   -0.94   -0.92   -0.9    -0.88   -0.84
-0.98   -0.96   -0.94   -0.92   -0.9    -0.88   -0.82
-0.98   -0.96   -0.94   -0.92   -0.9    -0.88   -0.8
-0.98   -0.96   -0.94   -0.92   -0.9    -0.88   -0.76
-0.98   -0.96   -0.94   -0.92   -0.9    -0.88   -0.74
-0.98   -0.96   -0.94   -0.92   -0.9    -0.88   0.72
```

Upon successful training **without the last row in the dataset** the NN successfully produces some mean value between 7 and 13 as output (viz. -0.79) when given sequence between 1 and 6. However, upon training with the last row (which acts like a noise) the prediction of sequence vary and produces output (viz. -0.19).

What I desire is that since there are more records in the dataset pointing the output in the range of -0.74 and -0.86, the NN must give preference to produce output within that range.

So is there any way I can teach the network to either ignore such noise in dataset or rather produce output nearest to the desired likely range.

I was looking at this paper [here](https://clgiles.ist.psu.edu/papers/MLJ-finance.pdf) where they have given input to RNN from SOM to reduce noise in dataset but I could not figure out way to implement it in my scenario.

Comment: That's a *very broad* question that probably isn't related to programming at all - *your* code in C# won't affect how the *library's* algorithm is implemented. Nor is there *noise* - your extra output is the *exact opposite* of the other values. Why do you think that's *noise*? It's 14% of the (tiny) training dataset! Use a realistic dataset if you want to see real results. Programs like R include both neural network packages *and* sample datasets you can use for meaningful training.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I agree the dataset is tiny (14% error) and may not be meaningful however its an example (and not a real data) I am looking towards approaching for noise reduction using classification technique followed by RNN regression. `removed the c# tag`

Comment: Just add a point: the [UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) contains a lot of sample datasets you can use to test your algorithms.